# Systematic mode collapse and its avoidance in gans

Tags: neural-networks, gan

I am looking for a gan architecture that does systematically mode collapse in one configuration (say A), and does not in a different configuration (say B).

The difference between configurations A and B should be small, e.g just the value of one hyperparameter or an architectural choice (use dropout or not),
but a part from this the gan architecture should be the same.

The ideal case would be if just the value of one hyperparameter is different,
and the outcome should be more or less systematic (mode collapse or not).

I looked for this a lot, could someone help me?